# CakePHP Layout template overriding view template

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-routing

I have installed CakePHP 3.8 and my layout template (/src/Template/Layout/default.ctp) is completely overriding my controller view (src/Template/Users/login.ctp).

I have echo'd & die()'d at the beginning/end of both files, so I know they are being called/rendered, but once default.ctp is called/rendered, login.ctp is gone.

I think this a routing issue but I'm not sure. I'm new to install/setup of CakePHP. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to StackOverflow. I guess you misunderstood the functionality of the CakePHP templating.

The layout files are supposed to override the view file. In CakePHP when a view renders first the layout is rendered and in that layout, the view is embedded in the place where you use the $this->fetch('content');.

that's the reason why all the dynamic content is placed in the view file and common content like the header and all in the layout.

I hope you got my point.

In case you have still any doubt feel free to ask. I'll be happy to help.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Such a simple statement for such a big deal. I'm having to upgrade from a much older version I did not install. I removed that very important line as I was getting errors. Thanks so much.